# Debugging SharePoint XSLT using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, sharepoint-2010, xslt

Is there a simple way to debug XSLT currently being run in SharePoint 2010?  I am running some federated searches, each of which use their own XSLT for transforming RSS feeds, but I cannot see a simple way to debug the XSLT in real time.  All that seems to to be possble is to edit the XSLT and load it.
I am currently running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on the 64 bit W2008 server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if the following link is helpful for you.

http://code-reflections.blogspot.com/2011/08/sharepoint-2010-debugging-xslt-list.html